# Infinitive in complex sentence: 'we will do your best in order to ensure the debate be vivid and fruitful.'

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Is 'We will do your best in order to ensure the debate be vivid and fruitful.' a grammatically correct sentence?

I am not sure if I used the infinitive correctly, is it better to place simply 'is' instead of 'be'?

Comment: "We will do our best in order to ensure the debate will be vivid and fruitful."  You can also use "is", but it is better to use the future tense.  I've flagged this as an English learning question and it is probably not appropriate here.

Comment: What I find odd about this is "**We** will do **your** best..". In English, **we** can do **our** best, and **you** can do **your** best, but **we** cannot do **your** best!

Comment: You cannot ensure (make certain) that a debate will take place in a particular way or have a predicted outcome. A debate is where speakers are encouraged to put forward opposing views and discuss them, so by its very nature, cannot be controlled. You can however, do your best to ensure the conditions are in place to facilitate or promote (give the opportunity and encourage) a vivid and fruitful debate. For example, you could write 'We will do our best to facilitate a vivid and fruitful debate'.

Comment: This question is not mere proofreading, because a particular concern (use of *be* or *is*) has been noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Be* is not an infinitive here; it is a subjunctive. You cannot order that something is so unless you are omnipotent: you can give orders that it should become so, perhaps *order that the flag be raised* (**Is** would be wrong there). On the other hand, you cannot believe that something be the case: *I believe the flag is now flying*. It is not clear which side of the  divide *ensure* falls on. Myself I think this use is performative, and so *be* is wrong as a hypercorrection, but the author obviously disagrees.

Comment: It may be attempting to be a subjunctive, but, at least in American English, *ensure* is no longer a verb that takes a subjunctive.

Comment: *Ensure that it be...* seems fairly well attested. On what are you basing this conclusion, Peter?

Comment: @Tim: mainly my gut feeling, but it's pretty solidly backed by [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ensure+that+it+be%2Censure+that+it+is%2C+important+that+it+be%2C+important+that+it+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Censure%20that%20it%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Censure%20that%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimportant%20that%20it%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimportant%20that%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor: fair enough. Moribund, but not quite dead yet.